# perl: use current date format in substitution part or regexp

Tags: regex, perl, date

I have a perl one-liner in a Makefile to edit files in place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(Package version:).*/$1 123/' myfile
```

That changes a string `Package version:` and adds a number (123 in this example). Now I would like to do the same but with the current date (in ISO format), so something like this

```
perl -pi -e 's/(Release date:).*/$1 <current date>/' myfile
```

How can I write the above `<current date>` to get the current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pi -e 's/(Release date:).*/$1 '"$(date +'%F %T')"'/' myfile
```

Comment: Careful, the answer relies on the `date` binary. The same result, but with portable code: `perl -MTime::Piece -pi -e '$t = localtime->strftime("%F %T"); s/(Release date:).*/$1 $t/' myfile`

Comment: Also consider

`perl -MPOSIX -pe 's/^(Release date:).*/strftime("$1%Y-%m-%d", localtime)/e;'`

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -MPOSIX -pi -e '$t=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime); s/(Release date:).*/$1 $t/;' myfile
```

http://ideone.com/J7eIB

Comment: @daxim Sorry I didnt notice the ISO date requirement. It's fixed now